# React-Native Install Error with Babel ES2015

Tags: react-native, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I am trying to start a new react-native project following the [Getting Started](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html) example in the projects docs. Below is the install and error I get. NODE is 5.2, NPM is 3.3.12. Mac is El Capitain.

I get an error: Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory referencing ES2015 relative to directory.

I then follow the advice [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35809331/2336356) and have both presets installed globally and locally in the project. You can see it in the npm ls -g command below that its installed globally. After installing it locally in the project, i get a peer deependency warning for react: UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react@15.0.2

I then installed react@15.0.2. I then re-run react-native run-ios and I get the same error:

```
Alains-MacBook-Pro:AwesomeProject klik$ react-native run-ios
/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:413
          throw new Error( /*istanbul ignore next*/"Couldn't find preset " + /*istanbul ignore next*/(0, _stringify2.default)(val) + " relative to directory " + /*istanbul ignore next*/(0, _stringify2.default)(dirname));
          ^

Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/Users/klik"
    at /Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:413:17
    at Array.map (native)
```

I then run npm install on the project and get the same error again.

```
Alains-MacBook-Pro:AwesomeProject klik$ npm -v
3.3.12
Alains-MacBook-Pro:AwesomeProject klik$ npm install
Alains-MacBook-Pro:AwesomeProject klik$ react-native run-ios
/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:413
          throw new Error( /*istanbul ignore next*/"Couldn't find preset " + /*istanbul ignore next*/(0, _stringify2.default)(val) + " relative to directory " + /*istanbul ignore next*/(0, _stringify2.default)(dirname));
          ^

Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/Users/klik"
    at /Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:413:17
    at Array.map (native)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:405:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:388:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:347:14)
    at OptionManager.addConfig (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:248:10)
    at OptionManager.findConfigs (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:454:16)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:502:12)
    at compile (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:112:69)
    at loader (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:158:14)
```

I then add a .babelrc file with the following JSON. This has worked on other projects for me after reading it on [Babeljs.io](https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-es2015/) and I saw it suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35694271/2336356) again so I tried it. It didnt work but produced this different error referencing the promise directory. This looks like it waiting for a promise to return with the ios file in the project, which doesnt exist because React-Native never completed the install. All I have for files in the project after running npm install are node_modules directory and package.json and the .babelrc file I added:

```
Alains-MacBook-Pro:AwesomeProject klik$ npm install
Alains-MacBook-Pro:AwesomeProject klik$ react-native run-ios
/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/promise/lib/done.js:10
      throw err;
      ^

Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, uv_chdir
    at Error (native)
    at process.chdir (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/graceful-fs/polyfills.js:18:9)
    at _runIOS (runIOS.js:51:11)
    at runIOS.js:24:5
    at tryCallTwo (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:45:5)
    at doResolve (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:200:13)
    at new Promise (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:66:3)
    at Array.runIOS (runIOS.js:23:10)
    at Object.run (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js:87:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/klik/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/lib/node_modules/react-native-cli/index.js:88:7)
```

This is the original install with error:

```
Alains-MacBook-Pro:~ klik$ npm ls -g --depth=0
/Users/klik/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/lib
├── babel-cli@6.8.0
├── babel-preset-es2015@6.6.0
├── babel-preset-react@6.5.0
├── cf-package@1.0.2
├── eslint@2.10.2
├── express@4.13.4
├── firebase-tools@3.0.0
├── gulp-cli@1.2.1
├── jshint@2.9.2
├── node-pre-gyp@0.6.28
├── nodemon@1.9.2
├── npm@3.3.12
├── react-native-cli@0.2.0
├── reindex-cli@0.4.1
├── rnpm@1.7.0
├── webpack@1.13.0
└── webpack-dev-server@1.14.1

Alains-MacBook-Pro:~ klik$ which node
**/Users/klik/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/bin/node**
Alains-MacBook-Pro:~ klik$ which npm
**/Users/klik/.nvm/versions/node/v5.2.0/bin/npm**
Alains-MacBook-Pro:~ klik$ watchman -v
4.5.0
Alains-MacBook-Pro:~ klik$ cd projects
Alains-MacBook-Pro:projects klik$ react-native init AwesomeProject
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in /Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject
Installing react-native package from npm...
/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:413
          throw new Error( /*istanbul ignore next*/"Couldn't find preset " + /*istanbul ignore next*/(0, _stringify2.default)(val) + " relative to directory " + /*istanbul ignore next*/(0, _stringify2.default)(dirname));
          ^

Error: Couldn't find preset "es2015" relative to directory "/Users/klik"
    at /Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:413:17
    at Array.map (native)
    at OptionManager.resolvePresets (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:405:20)
    at OptionManager.mergePresets (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:388:10)
    at OptionManager.mergeOptions (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:347:14)
    at OptionManager.addConfig (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:248:10)
    at OptionManager.findConfigs (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:454:16)
    at OptionManager.init (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:502:12)
    at compile (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:112:69)
    at loader (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-register/lib/node.js:158:14)
Alains-MacBook-Pro:projects klik$
```

Any ideas come to mind? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

tl;dr.
`npm i babel-preset-react-native --save-dev`
`$ echo '{"presets": ["react-native"]}' > .babelrc`

So the problem as noted in the first error starts in the babel options manager:
 `at OptionManager.init (/Users/klik/projects/AwesomeProject/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/options/option-manager.js:502:12)`

While trying to figure out how to get any react-native project running, I came across [Este's DevStack](https://github.com/este/este) for react-native. When I installed, it worked as advertised. I went to the code to see why this worked and not one single other worked. Este has a .babelrc file. This is it:
Este .babelrc
    {
      "presets": ["react-native"],
      "env": {
        "production": {
          "plugins": [
            "transform-react-constant-elements",
            "transform-react-inline-elements"
          ]
        }
      }
    }

I added the "env" setting to the .babelrc i created earlier. This is the current .babelrc file.

```
{
  "retainLines": true,
  "compact": true,
  "comments": false,
  "plugins": [],
  "presets": ["react", "react-native"],
  "env": {  
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-constant-elements",
        "transform-react-inline-elements"
      ]   
  },
  "sourceMaps": false,
}
```

I added this options configuration into each previous project including the one that is the subject of the question and everyone of them worked. This includes the [Firebase](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2016/01/the-beginners-guide-to-react-native-and_84.html), example. They all worked. Apparently, Babel 6 no longer does [transforms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33440848/2336356) by default and you have to enable it. I checked the [React-Native Babel Preset](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/babel-preset) on github and it handles transforms. So this is the new .babelrc file and it works.

```
{"presets": ["react-native"]}
```

Turns out @jaxoncreed has the right solution in his [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35692139/2336356). The [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35694271/2336356) there suggests there is a default fallback .babelrc file that will be used if you put one in. In the copy of the the tutorial project downloaded a few days ago, that file doesn't exist. So the short answer is I need to add the .babelrc file in the project.

```
npm i babel-preset-react-native --save-dev

$ echo '{"presets": ["react-native"]}' > .babelrc
```